# After upgrading the firmware on my IC-7300, there's a new preset in a language I can't understand, what is it?

Tags: icom-ic-7300

I recently upgraded the firmware on my Icom IC-7300 and a new menu item appeared: "Preset". I assume this is a way to save different radio configurations but I haven't looked into it yet. Inside "Preset" there were two items, FT8 which I'm familiar with and another written in a language I don't understand:

[image]

I guess it's Japanese, but I don't speak so I can't be sure. What does it say? What is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It says 通常 ("tsūjō" or "tsuujou"), which means "ordinary" or "normal". As for why it's showing up on yours, I'm guessing something funny happened in the update process. Ordinarily on a 7300 set for English, that preset would be called "Normal".

The Normal preset sets the mode to USB, sets the filters to values that should be good for voice (rather than data) operation, and resets a bunch of other options to sane defaults. If you want to see the details, [this post from K0PIR](https://www.k0pir.us/icom-7300-firmware-v1-40-3-big-improvements/) has screen captures of the settings — or you can go into the menu on the 7300 and view them yourself.

Comment: Mh. I wonder if I got the wrong firmware. I'm going to do a factory reset to see what happens.

Comment: Yup, after factory reset, now it says "Normal". Thank you.

Comment: @PabloFernandez-M0ONPACI1DM I think the updater writes the presets into memory, separately from the actual firmware update, and it reads your language preference to decide what values to put there. And somehow... it got confused in your case. :)